# Not able to call the solidity function through App.js? Anyone know how to call a solidity function?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, metamask, javascript

I'm trying to call a Solidity function from `App.js`, but I'm unsuccessful even after a number of tries.

Its a very simple function `betOnTeam()`.  Inside this function I just want to check condition and give a call to another function `update()`, 
but I'm not even able to view logs in the console (can't even call `betOnTeam()`).

So here is the function in `.sol` file that I'm trying to call:

```solidity
function betOnTeam(uint team) public {
  emit LogInfo("Inside betOnTeam-----------");
  if(team == 1) {
    update();
  }
}
```

This function accepts an `int` so I'm providing it through `App.js`:

```js
function ready(){
  document.getElementById("bet").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var contract = web3.eth.contract(OraclizeContract.abi).at(OraclizeContract.address);

    var team = document.querySelector("#bet #team").value;

    if(team == "Home")
    {
      team = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      team = 2;
    }
    console.log(team) ------------>> THIS SHOWS 1 IF HOME SELECTED

    // Now i am calling the .sol function

    contract.betOnTeam(team, function(err, transactionHash) {
      if (!err)
        console.log(transactionHash); 
    })   
  })
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

I can'not call the function by passing the argument I have even tried

```js
contract.betOnTeam.call(team, function(err, transactionHash) {
  if (!err)
  console.log(transactionHash); 
})
```

`.call` gives me a blank array on the console nothing else
otherwise without using `.call` I can'not see any error on the console

`update()` function:

```solidity
function update()
  payable
  public {
  // Check if we have enough remaining funds
  if (oraclize_getPrice("URL") > address(this).balance) {
    emit LogInfo("Oraclize query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
  } else {
    emit LogInfo("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");

    // Using XPath to to fetch the right element in the JSON response
    oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://api.crowdscores.com/v1/matches/123945?api_key=93c4c515196741beaf5e4528b64ea511).outcome.winner");
  }
}
```

Comment: any help is highly appreciated, I cannot call the function if you cant understand the question I am really trying my best to explain I can explain again. Please help if you know anything

Comment: can you change `var team = document.querySelector("#bet #team").value;` to `var team = document.querySelector("#bet", " #team").value;` and try.

Comment: please also mention the `web3` version you are using.

Comment: "web3": "^0.20.0",

Comment: nope by changing i can't even access the value right now i can access the value as shows in the code -->> console.log statement

Comment: can you update your question with `update` method?

Comment: updated the code